# how to exclude range of numbers using regular expression

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to write a regular expression in order to cover all numbers starting with 1809 and excluding some ranges:

#### Ranges needed to be excluded

Starting with 1809 and followed by:

- 201,203,205,212,214,222,228,232,235,249,256,260,2643983
- 266,2724728,2725724,299,315,330,350-354,356-361,3670229
- 370,383,386,389,391,394-399,401-411,413,424-429,451-469
- 477-481,484,485,488,490-499,501,502,504-507,509,510,512
- 514,516,517,519,520,543,545,606,615,618,661-668,670-675
- 694,696-698,7079832,710,720-722,727,729,744,747,749-753
- 756-765,767,769,773,774,778,7837079,7839522,792-799,809
- 823-826,828,830-832,834-844,895-898,950,953

Comment: It would be much better if you introduce the example of raw strings.

Comment: For example the below range need to be excluded from all numbers started with 1809 (^1809 without the following RE):
^1809(20[135]|21[24]|22[28]|23[25]|24[9]|256|26[06]|2643983|27247)

Comment: May be list of numbers to be included much shorter or easy for grupping?

Comment: Maybe regex is not the right tool for this job. [What are you _really_ trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: I will use this for an application to control a traffic, the destination will be just numbers thus the only one solution i have is to write a regular expression that match
 **everything start with 1809 and remove the above list from it** (the big list of numbers could be modified any time)...

1809 or the list of number means nothing it is just an example.
The idea here is how to exclude numbers using regex...

Answer (score 1):

I manually wrote the regex which matches all patterns you want excluded:

`/1809(20[135]|21[24]|22[28]|23[25]|249|256|26[06]|2643983|2724728|2725724|299|315|330|35[0-46-9]|36[01]|3670229|370|38[369]|39[14-9]|40[1-9]|41[013]|42[4-9]|45[1-9]|46[0-9]|47[7-9]|48[01458]|49[0-9]|50[124-79]|51[024679]|520|54[35]|606|61[58]|66[1-8]|67[0-5]|69[46-8]|7079832|710|72[0-279]|74[479]|75[0-36-9]|76[0-579]|77[348]|7837079|7839522|79[2-9]|809|82[3-68]|83[0-24-9]|84[0-4]|89[5-8]|95[03])/`

I'm not sure how you would automatically generate this regular expression given the above information though.